# What does it mean if totalMemory is small, but totalPss is very huge?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-fragmentation

We have a problem with our app. Over time we have noticed that the `totalPss` value gets very large (depending on the device, it will be 300-700Mb):

```
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    int pids[] = new int[1];
    pids[0] = pid;
    android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
    if (memoryInfoArray.length > 0)
    {
        android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo thisProcessMemoryInfo = memoryInfoArray[0];

        Log.d("totalPss", thisProcessMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()+"");
    }
```

Here is a graph showing results from a typical run:

[image: processMemoryInfo]

But, at the same time, the `totalMemory` value never gets very large (40-50Mb at max, but falls to 10Mb after GC).

```
    Log.d("totalMem", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+"");
```

Here is a graph showing that from the same run as above (please ignore the units, it is actually in bytes):

[image]

`getMemoryClass` for this device indicates that we have 192Mb available for the app:

```
    Log.d("getMemoryClass", activityManager.getMemoryClass()+"");
```

Our memory usage pattern is to make a number of large allocations over time which are frequently released. After a long time of this, a large allocation will fail which typically causes the app to fail.

It seems like we are probably having fragmentation, does this seem correct? Can we resolve this by using the `largeHeap` attribute (my intuition is that it would not)? Are there any tools to help diagnose this more certainly?

Comment: It looks like `MemoryInfo#getTotalPss()` is in kb. Are you sure `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` refers to your apps available memory? `/proc/[pid]/statm` reports a different value for total size.

Comment: Yes I am quite sure that it refers to the total heap size: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()

Comment: >Returns the number of bytes taken by the heap at its current size. The heap may expand or contract over time, as the number of live objects increases or decreases. See maxMemory() for the maximum heap size, and freeMemory() for an idea of how much the heap could currently contract.

Comment: I think that the values in e.g. statm, smaps and `getTotalPss` are relating to the count of pages allocated by the OS, while `totalMemory` relates to the heap size for the Java runtime